# vba routine not working after first working perfectly

Tags: excel, vba, office-2016

My routine, which worked perfect before, suddenly results in errors. I do not understand why, the only thing I can think of is a newer office version makes this routine not work anymore. We changed from office 2013 to office 2016 (already some time ago but I have not used this template for a while).

this is the code that results in errors:

```
Sub kopie_formule()
Dim x As Integer
Dim aantalrijen As Integer
Dim NB As Variant

With Worksheets("Promo Evaluatie")

'.Unprotect Password:="TM"
x = 13
    aantalrijen = .Range("B14", .Range("B13").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    .Range("Y14:Y" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-7]-RC[-2])),""#N/B"",IF(RC[-7]-RC[-2]<0,0,(RC[-7]-RC[-2])))"
    .Range("Z14:Z" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]/RC[-8]),""#N/B"",RC[-1]/RC[-8])"
    .Range("AA14:AA" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-9]/RC[-5]),"""",RC[-9]/RC[-5])"
    .Range("AB14:AB" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-12]*RC[-2]),""#N/B"",RC[-12]*RC[-2])"
    .Range("AC14:AC" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-9]/RC[-24]/RC[-8]),""#N/B"",RC[-9]/RC[-24]/RC[-8])"
    .Range("AD14:AD" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-7]/RC[-25]/RC[-6]),""#N/B"",RC[-7]/RC[-25]/RC[-6])"
    .Range("AE14:AE" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(RC[-12]="""",""#N/B"",IF(RC[-10]="""",""#N/B"",IF(RC[-26]="""",""#N/B"",RC[-12]-(RC[-10]*RC[-26]))))"
    .Range("AF14:AF" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*0.5),""#N/B"",RC[-1]*0.5)"
    .Range("AG14:AG" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-1]*0.5)-RC[-5]-RC[-18]),""#N/B"",(RC[-1]*0.5)-RC[-5]-RC[-18])"
    .Range("AH14:AH" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-2]*0.5)-RC[-20]-RC[-6]-RC[-19]),""#N/B"",(RC[-2]*0.5)-RC[-20]-RC[-6]-RC[-19])"
    .Range("AI14:AI" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-21]+RC[-19]+RC[-20])/RC[-4]),""#N/B"",IF(((RC[-21]+RC[-19]+RC[-20])/RC[-4])<0,""#N/B"",((RC[-21]+RC[-19]+RC[-20])/RC[-4])))"
    .Range("AJ14:AJ" & aantalrijen + x) = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-22]+RC[-20]+RC[-8]+RC[-21])/RC[-5]),""#N/B"",IF(((RC[-22]+RC[-20]+RC[-8]+RC[-21])/RC[-5])<0,""#N/B"",(RC[-22]+RC[-20]+RC[-8]+RC[-21])/RC[-5]))"
```

this is the error:

> Error 1004 during execution: by application or object defined error.

Could this be caused because my code is not compatible with Office 2016?

Comment: What error do you get and on which line, does is occur during run-time or before the code even starts?

Comment: sorry, should have included the error indeed. The error I get is for all those lines when I try each of them. This is the error: Error 1004 during execution: by application or object defined error.
I thought it might be a mistake in the first line so I changed that into a comment but the same happens with the next line, and the next and so on. And first it worked perfeclty.

Comment: What value does `aantalrijen` have when code stops on error?

Comment: 227. added with 13 is results in 240. Which is the exact last line which is filled with data.

Comment: Minor comment, but it's probably slightly safer to use`.Range("Y14:Y" & aantalrijen + x).Formula2R1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR((RC[-7]-RC[-2])),""#N/B"",IF(RC[-7]-RC[-2]<0,0,(RC[-7]-RC[-2])))"`, et cetera

Comment: @DutchArjo You see, that information is missing from your example - you `Dim aantalrijen As Integer`  (and unlike VB.Net, there is **zero** advantage to using `Integer` in VBA - always use `Long` instead) but you never set it.  This means you do not have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - the error might be caused by *other* code that you've stripped out!